# can we add 1 template to 2 view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i wonder if i can add 1 template like `art_detail.html` into 2 views `template_name`
if so `object`contains which ones data?
unfortunately i got a problem with adding comment to posts ,i asked it in reddit but since got 0answer i would be pleased if you answer it:https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1029qyk/why_createview_doesnt_create_text_input/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

to create comment input i made a `comment` model and view and added it to `art_detail.html`(same html for `ArtDetailView`),but form doesn't make any input

model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    art = models.ForeignKey(Art,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.writer.username
```

view:

```
class CommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'art_detail.html'
    fields = ['text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.writer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

template:

```
<div class="comment">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="comment">ارسال</button>
    </form>
    {% for comment in object.comment_set.all %}
        <span>{{comment.writer}}</span>
        <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

i also added url but dont if its ok or not:

```
path('art_detail/<int:pk>/add_comment/',views.CommentView.as_view(),name='add_comment')
```

Comment: You can also post your code here instead of a Reddit link.

Comment: right i should respect you